# Split columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm cleaning up an Excel file, but in a row there is a column with a long answer and I will like to split it into multiple columns

I'm using this code:

```
new = df["¿Qué productos sueles adquirir para hidratarse?"]= df["¿Qué productos sueles adquirir para hidratarse?"].str.split(" ", n = 2 , expand = True)
```

But when I print out the dataframe there is just one column and not the others, how could I make it?

Comment: can you add how you expect the output ??

Comment: It's way easier to read code written in language one understands. Please write code in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'test':['One Two Three']})
>>> df[1], df[2], df[3] = df['test'].str.split(' ',n=2,expand=True)
>>> df
            test  1  2  3
0  One Two Three  0  1  2
```

OR

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'test':['One Two Three']})
>>> df = df['test'].str.split(' ',n=2,expand=True)
>>> df
     0    1      2
0  One  Two  Three
```